# Using Selenium and Java, I need a better way to select radio button than "CSSSelector" because of same-named values in different radio groups

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to test a page that has two radio button groups on it. The first group is this, called "Human Resources issue?" and the choices are Yes/No and the default value is "No."

```
<label class="label">
    <input onkeydown="selectOptionOnPressingSpace(event)" 
     class="FormFieldRadioCheckbox" name="HUMAN_RESOURCES_ISSUE_D" 
     onclick="" value="1" onfocus="window.status=unescape('Field name is 
     HUMAN_RESOURCES_ISSUE_D');" onblur="window.status=''" type="radio"> Yes
</label>

<label class="label">
    <input onkeydown="selectOptionOnPressingSpace(event)" 
     class="FormFieldRadioCheckbox" name="HUMAN_RESOURCES_ISSUE_D" 
     onclick="" value="0" onfocus="window.status=unescape('Field name is 
     HUMAN_RESOURCES_ISSUE_D');" onblur="window.status=''" checked="" type="radio"> No
</label>
```

As you can see, the choices Yes/No correspond to values of 1 and 0, respectively

Here is the second radio button group, called "Impact" and the choices are Critical/Major/Minor and there is no default value.

```
<label class="label">
    <input onkeydown="selectOptionOnPressingSpace(event)" 
    class="FormFieldRadioCheckbox" name="DEV_IMPACT_P" onclick=";
    processDocument('CMD_REFRESH' , 'ETQ$ANCHOR=DEV_IMPACT_P&
    amp;REFRESH_FIELD_NAME=DEV_IMPACT_P');" value="1" 
    onfocus="window.status=unescape('Field name is DEV_IMPACT_P');" 
    onblur="window.status=''" type="radio"> Critical
</label>

<label class="label">
    <input onkeydown="selectOptionOnPressingSpace(event)" 
    class="FormFieldRadioCheckbox" name="DEV_IMPACT_P" onclick=";
    processDocument('CMD_REFRESH' , 'ETQ$ANCHOR=DEV_IMPACT_P&
    amp;REFRESH_FIELD_NAME=DEV_IMPACT_P');" value="2" 
    onfocus="window.status=unescape('Field name is DEV_IMPACT_P');" 
    onblur="window.status=''" type="radio"> Major
</label>

<label class="label">
    <input onkeydown="selectOptionOnPressingSpace(event)" 
    class="FormFieldRadioCheckbox" name="DEV_IMPACT_P" onclick=";
    processDocument('CMD_REFRESH' , 'ETQ$ANCHOR=DEV_IMPACT_P&
    amp;REFRESH_FIELD_NAME=DEV_IMPACT_P');" value="3" 
    onfocus="window.status=unescape('Field name is DEV_IMPACT_P');" 
    onblur="window.status=''" type="radio"> Minor
</label>
```

Here the choices Critical/Major/Minor correspond to values of 1,2, and 3, respectively. Therein lies the problem. I need to test all 6 combinations of these buttons (Yes + Critical, Yes + Major, Yes + Minor, No + Critical, No + Major, No + Minor).

The first two tests (No/Minor and No/Major) went without a hitch. But when I tried No/Critical, I had the problem. You can probably already see why. Because Human Resources Issue defaults to "no" I didn't need to select any elements for that radio button group. For Impact, i would use:

```
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='3']")).click();
```

for minor, and

```
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='2']")).click();
```

for major. But when I tried to do

```
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='1']")).click();
```

for critical, it changed "Human Resources Issue?" to "Yes" and didn't do anything for Impact. That is because the developer (either our in-house developer or the developer(s) from the company who wrote the program) used the value of 1 for both Human Resources issue "Yes" and Impact "Critical."

My question is, looking at the HTML code for the radio button groups is there a way to do this that

a) does not require me to use the XPATH (I have the xpath and can do it that way, but based on the way these are buried, the xpaths are really, really long! Plus xpath to me is a last resort!)

b) does not involve me bothering the developer to change the input values (although eventually I'll probably have to get her to do that, it's just I am not sure how much of this is the out of the box functionality of the program or the developer edits, not that it matters.)

Thanks so much for your help!

-The Munch

Comment: Is it possible to just add an `id` to each element? I would just add a unique/descriptive id to each element and be done with it.

Comment: That would violate condition b, harrassing the developer. I'm wondering if there is a way to do it based on what is already there, that does not use x-path

Comment: I see, I would just add it myself but if you don't have that option then the accepted answer is a good option.

Comment: I *could* add it myself... but the SQA guy meddling in developer's code is highly frowned upon where i work. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join css attribute selects to make it more specific like that:

```
By.cssSelector("input[name='DEV_IMPACT_P'][value='1']")
```

Comment: Perfect! That worked - I tried name, but i must not have formatted it correctly or something. Thanks very much!!